# consuming Server Sent Events with Webflux or Flux-producing Endpoint in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

How can I consume Server Sent Events with Spring Integration? I am aware Spring supports SSE with Webflux, but how to convert the incoming Flux into separate Message instances? And possibly wrap this code into some Spring-Integration-Lifecycle-aware component (MessageProducerSupport?)

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://myhost:8080/sse");
ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type
 = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};

Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
  .uri("/stream-sse")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(type);

eventStream.subscribe(
  content -> ;/* here I believe the message should be produced/sent to a channel */ );
```

Answer (score 1):

See Spring Integration WebFlux Outbound Gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/webflux.html#webflux-outbound:

> The `setExpectedResponseType(Class<?>)` or `setExpectedResponseTypeExpression(Expression)` identifies the target type of the response body element conversion. If `replyPayloadToFlux` is set to true, the response body is converted to a `Flux` with the provided `expectedResponseType` for each element, and this `Flux` is sent as the payload downstream. Afterwards, you can use a `splitter` to iterate over this Flux in a reactive manner.

```
WebFlux.outboundGateway("http://myhost:8080/sse/stream-sse")
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .replyPayloadToFlux(true)
            .setExpectedResponseTypeExpression(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {})
```

To make it start working just after an application is ready, yo can implement an `ApplicationRunner` to send a "void" message into a channel for the flow with that `WebFlux.outboundGateway()`. I don't think we need a special, dedicated component just for SSE requesting and producing. The combination of existing components is fully enough.